# Apple Mail in SL using excessive data

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I am using Apple Mail on Snow Leopard. It seems to use excessive data, around 1.5 GB a day. I don't receive mails remotely close to that size obviously.

Does anybody have any idea what's happening. Its very consistent. Turn Mail off, and the download goes away.

Much appreciated.

Comment: POP or IMAP accounts? How many of them? How often do you check for new mail? Any activity shown in Mail > Window > Activity?

Comment: When you say "excessive data", do you mean excessive amounts of network traffic, excessive amounts of RAM, or excessive amounts of disk space? When you say "Turn Mail off", are you talking about quitting Mail.app?

Comment: Do you have Mail.app configured to read any RSS feeds?

Comment: @MacLemon IMAP - Gmail, IMAP - MobileMe accounts. MobileMe account rarely gets any mail. I dont check mail manually. Only check when it displays a badge. Usually just text messages, with rare attachments. Definitely not worth 1.5 GB.Activity shown in Window>Activity - Gmail updating cache directory. Synchronizing with server, communicating with server. This happens pretty much all the time. Is this normal ?

Comment: @Spliff - excessive network traffic - around 1.5 GB a day.

Quit mail. No RSS feeds.